# How to extract the real value of unicode characters in python?

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I'm trying to built a parser of a website using "scrapy". My current aim is to extract all the titles of the listing at the following page: https://www.avito.ru/leningradskaya_oblast_kirovsk/kvartiry/prodam/1-komnatnye (language: russian).

However, using

```
response.xpath('here_comes_the_path_to_a_title').extract()
```

i get something like this:

**[u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 56 \u043c\xb2, 4/5 \u044d\u0442.',
 u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 32 \u043c\xb2, 3/3 \u044d\u0442.',
 u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 48 \u043c\xb2, 11/16 \u044d\u0442.',
 u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 42 \u043c\xb2, 1/4 \u044d\u0442.',
 u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 37 \u043c\xb2, 1/9 \u044d\u0442.',
 u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 42 \u043c\xb2, 3/4 \u044d\u0442.',
 u'\n 1-\u043a \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 45 \u043c\xb2, 3/3 \u044d\u0442.',]**

which is obviously a list of all titles encoded in unicode.

Now, here comes the question. I would like to have these items (values of the above list) *in their original form* (like they were written in original language at the internet page). 
For example, i would like to have a dictionary:

```
{'title': 'the_first_value_of_the_above_list_in_original_language'}
```

And later store the list of such dictionaries in a JSON or CSV file.

Is it possible to decode these unicode strings and to get their original values?

*p.s. I also noticed that i get the original value using print function in python shell:

```
>>> str = u'\n 1-\u043a  \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 56 \u043c\xb2, 4/5 \u044d\u0442.'
>>> print str
```

but i have no idea how to extract this value and write it in a file*

Comment: Your dict already contains exactly the strings you want. Python just displays unicode escapes to avoid confusion. For example, if you have a string with the right-to-left switchy thing in it, it's a lot easier to understand the dict's contents if you get a unicode escape than if everything is suddenly backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... which is obviously a list of all titles encoded in unicode.

Incorrect. It is the representation of the characters contained in the string. The string itself does contain the characters you expect, as you've discovered using the REPL.

If you need to write those characters out to a file then you will need to choose an encoding for the file and use it on opening.

```
with io.open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
```