# Encode facebook-sdk cyrillic response in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, encoding, flask

I've got a list of strings as Facebook API response using Flask

```
posts_json = graph.get_object(id=address, fields="posts.limit(12){message,link,full_picture}")
```

Some of the string messages are cyrillic. I need to send this content to GUI, Facebook API response decoded to unicode, thus I'm trying to encode it first, but any known to my encoding doesn't work for the cyrillic content.

I tried

```
item['message'] = post[u'message'].encode('cp850', errors='replace')
```

The result is like

```
"message": "??????? ? ??? ?????????? ???????????. ????????????
```

Also 'cp866' and 'ascii' with '???...' and '/x...' results.

My original decoded message looks like this:

```
u'message': u'\u0421 \u0447\u0435\u043c \u043d\u043e\u0441\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0442\u043e\u043f \u0432 \u043f\u0430\u0439\u0435\u0442\u043a\u0438? \u041a\u0430\u043a
```

What can I use to encode cyrillic properly?
Thanks in advance.

Note: All other content I successfully encoded with 'utf-8'.

Update: 'utf-8' transformed my message to 
    '\xd0\xa1 \xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf \xd0\xb2'

Comment: Have you tried item['message'].decode('utf-8') ?

Comment: I encoded all other fields with 'utf-8', but it doesn't cover cyrillic, that's why I'm asking which encoding type to use for cyrillic in Python

Comment: _“that's why I'm asking which encoding type to use for cyrillic in Python”_ – UTF-8, of course. Everything else does not make much sense.

Comment: unfortunately, utf-8 doesn't work for this case, probably, something wrong with my source string or I don't know.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "original decoded message" is already unicode. You can tell by the 'u' at the beginning of the string.

As [a comment on a related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954409/how-to-extract-the-real-value-of-unicode-characters-in-python?rq=1#comment46162549_28954409) explains:

> Python just displays unicode escapes to avoid confusion. For example, if you have a string with the right-to-left switchy thing in it, it's a lot easier to understand the dict's contents if you get a unicode escape than if everything is suddenly backwards.

You shouldn't need to do any encoding or decoding and should be able to use the string as is. Try `print(post["message"])`.

Comment: I know about unicode, actually, the reason of my question is how to decode (or encode) this string to pass it to GUI, because the main my problem in displaying this message on client side. 
BTW, print(...) in python shows '/u...'.

Comment: Are you saying that `print(u'\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0438\u0442\u044c'`) doesn't print out `носить` for you? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: You're right when I use exactly `print post[u'message']` construction, it displays in cyrillic, despite on `print my_json_with_cyrillic_mes_inside`. So the problem is in the way to pass variables to GUI. Thank you